# Sufficient statistic for Bernoulli r.v.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be a iid sample of the Bernoulli ($p$) distribution. Consider the statistic $T = X_1X_2 + X_3$. Show that $T$ is not sufficient for p.

I did $$P(X=x|T=t)=\frac{P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=t-x_1x_2)}{P(T=t)}$$I'm stuck because I don't know how to calculate ${P(T=t)}.$

Comment: Hint: It is probably easiest to do this problem by the Neyman factorization theorem.

Comment: Can you use the factorisation theorem to show a statistic is not sufficient? I thought it was to only prove sufficiency.  Btw, just curious as to how one would find  $P(T=t)$ above.

Comment: Yeah you may be right about that, oops. You can find$P(T=t)$ mechanically. $$P(T=0) = P(X_1=0,X_2=0,X_3=0) + P(X_1=0,X_2=1,X_3=0) +P(X_1=1,X_2=0,X_3=0)$$  $$P(T=2)=P(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=1)$$ $$P(T=1) = 1-P(T=0)-P(T=2)$$

Comment: You know that $X_1+X_2+X_3$ is the minimal sufficient statistic and depends on all variables while T does not depend on $X_2$ is $X_1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Law of Total Probability, partitioned on $X_3$

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(T{=}t)~ = & ~ \mathsf P(X_3{=}0)~\mathsf P(X_1X_2{=}t)+\mathsf P(X_3{=}1)~\mathsf P(X_1X_2{=}t{-}1)\\[1ex] = & ~ (1-p)~\mathsf P(X_1X_2{=}t)+p~\mathsf P(X_1X_2{=}t{-}1)
 \\[2ex]\mathsf P(X_1X_2 {=} z) ~ = & ~ \begin{cases}1-p^2 & : z=0 \\ p^2 & : z=1\\ 0 & :\textsf{otherwise}\end{cases} 
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(T{=}t) ~ = & ~ \begin{cases} (1-p)(1-p^2) + 0 & : t=0 \\ (1-p)p^2+p(1-p^2) & : t=1 & \\ 0+p^3 & : t=2\\0 & :\textsf{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\[1ex]
= & ~ \begin{cases} 1-p-p^2+p^3 & : t=0 \\ p+p^2-2p^3 & : t=1 & \\ p^3 & : t=2\\0 & :\textsf{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\[3ex]
\mathsf P(X_1{=}x, X_2{=}y, X_3{=}t-xy) ~= & ~\begin{cases} (1-p)^3 & : (x,y,t)=(0,0,0)
\\ (1-p)^2p & : (x,y,t)\in\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}
\\ (1-p)p^2 & : (x,y,t)\in\{ (1,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,1)\}
\\ p^3 & : (x,y,t)=(1,1,2)
\\ 0 & : \textsf{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$